# Curve to fit points

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find the equation that fits the following points:

$1,0.0105;
2,0.181;
3,0.47;
4,0.755;
5,1.01;
6,1.22;
7,1.39;
8,1.54;
9,1.67;
10,1.79;
11,1.88;
12,1.96;
13,2.03;
14,2.10;
15,2.15;
16,2.21;
17,2.26;
18,2.30;
19,2.34;
20,2.37;
21,2.40;
40,2.73$

To me it looks like tan(theta) except sideways, but how do I get the function to go on its side? See:

http://i421.photobucket.com/albums/pp292/SharkD2161/Support/flowlines_test_plots_zps60e790dc.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning a function "on its side" roughly means exchanging the roles of the $x$ and $y$ axes, which is to say swapping the domain and the codomain. The input becomes the output and the other way 'round. That is, you want (something related to) the *inverse* of the tangent function, which is called the *arctangent* and written $\arctan$, $\operatorname{atan}$, or $\tan^{-1}$.

**Caution 1:** the tangent function is periodic, so it doesn't have an inverse over its entire domain, but if you restrict the domain to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ things should work out well.

**Caution 2:** Although $\tan^2 x = (\tan x)^2$ by convention, $\tan^{-1} x$ has nothing to do with $(\tan x)^{-1}$, the latter being the *cotangent* of $x$.

**Caution 3:** I haven't actually looked at the points, and, more importantly, I don't know where they came from, but just because something *looks* like an inverse tangent (or any other sort of curve) doesn't mean that that's actually an appropriate curve to fit. Ideally, you would fit a curve that you have some theoretical reason to suspect is the right sort for your data based on what they *mean*.

Comment: Thanks. Atan seems to be what I was looking for, though I am having trouble tweaking it to fit better.

Comment: @posfan12: I finally had a chance to look at the graph, and it really doesn't look much like an arctangent to me. Near the origin it behaves completely differently, and going the other way it's not even clear that it's bounded above. I would think again about that. Where do these data come from?

Comment: The source is from here: https://www.geogebra.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=32792  I am trying to scale the figure so that the "eyes" of the curve are always the same distance from the origin. Or at least be able to calculate the distance.

Comment: I found the formula I needed. It was in the code I used to generate the points. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. :(

Comment: @posfan12: As long as you learned one or two things along the way, I don't think anyone will mind.

Comment: @posfan12: Very well. I am curious to know what is the formula, if it is not indiscreet.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a polynomial regression
Set up a matrix of any degree you want, see example below

[image: Like here] 
Then solve the system of equations if it's manageable or have a CAS solve the system of equations for \begin{align}a0,a1,a2,a3...\end{align}

See [here for details](http://arachnoid.com/sage/polynomial.html)

OR you could pop the values into excel, scatter plot the points then add the trend line, exponential or polynomial and the equation as well as it's R^2 value to chose the best fit.
For a logarithmic regression you should get \begin{align}y=0.9023Ln(x)-0.3294\end{align} and an \begin{align}R^2=0.9735\end{align}

For a polynomial regression of degree 3 I get \begin{align}0.0003x^3-0.0162x^2+0.3534x-0.996\end{align} and an \begin{align}R^2=0.983\end{align}

You could do a transformation for a square root fit

Answer (score 0):

Many functions are likely to be optimized in order to abtain a good fit with the data set.

For example a polynomial, such as it was already explained.

Another example with an exponential function (3 parameters) is shown in attachment.

Usually the non-linear Least Squares Fitting requires an initial guess and iterative process for numerical computation. The result given in attachement was obtain thanks to an unusual straightforward method without initial guess and without iteration. The computation method is given page 17 in the paper "Régressions et équations intégrales" published on Scribd :

http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents

Note : the fitting should be much better if the last point (40 , 2.73) was suppressed

[image]